# How to make IPython display work when called from a function

Tags: jupyter-notebook

So I understand on a surface level how to render html, using the display function:

```
IPython.display.HTML('<b>FOOBAR</b>')
```

But what if I want to create a generic function to dynamically render html (i.e how do I make display work in a function.) For instance:

```
def foo():
    IPython.display.HTML('<b>FOOBAR</b>')

foo() # Does not render anything :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IPython.display.HTML`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.HTML) only creates a display object. It doesn't display it. Such objects are only auto-displayed if the last statement of a cell is an expression statement with such an object as the expression's value.

In any other context, you need to call [`IPython.display.display`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) to display the object:

```
def foo():
    IPython.display.display(IPython.display.HTML('<b>FOOBAR</b>'))
```